# Marklogic Java, specify length of a result of a query

Tags: java, marklogic

I'm wondering how to specify the length (NOT the pagelength) of the result of a query in Marklogic with the Java API.
Example: I want to search for the term `mark` and I want the result to be of length 4. This will only return documents where exactly the term `mark` is attached to some key in a document. If I search for `mark` and I want the result to be of length 10, then `mark twain` will be a valid result.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to get close by using wildcard searches (as in "mark??????").

You have to configure the indexes to support wildcard searches. There are some additional considerations (especially for matching whitespace characters):

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/wildcard

For efficiency, consider using a word lexicon on a JSON property, on a XML element, or on a field defined through the Admin UI instead of on the entire database.

Hoping that helps,

Comment: OK, then 'mark??????' will solve the search for 'mark' with length 10. But the search for 'mark' with length 4 is still not possible right?

Comment: An element value query or JSON property value query with the exact option (and indexes configured as suggested in the Usage section) will match the exact value. See: http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-value-query

Comment: Yes, but then I have to pre-specify on which key the searched value will match. I don't want that.